# How to disable the wifi switch on the Dell laptop?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, hardware

I have a dell laptop, which has a hardware wifi switch on the side. The problem is that it seems to have some loose contact, even with a minor touch, it gets triggered and switches off the wifi and rfkill lists it as "Hard blocked".

Now the issue just turned worse as the switch seems to have some sort of a loose connection, turning it back on doesn't seem to work, which is most likely a haradware issue.

I need to know if there's a way I can disable the switch so I'm not bothered by it and I won't use it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to remove the wifi card and put a small piece of tape on pin 20, there is a video on youtube- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzAKcmlaH1M